# Создать вложенный словарь из списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Напишите код для преобразования списка из целых чисел произвольной длины во словарь, вложенность которого зависит от длины списка.

Например, если перед вами был бы такой список

```
[100, 55, 77, 55, 89]
```

то он должен превратится в такой словарь

```
{100: {55: {77: {55: 89}}}}
```

На вход программе поступают числа для списка в одну строку, гарантируется, что в списке будет как минимум два элемента.

Ваша задача вывести полученный словарь

Вот мое решение, но оно верно только для списка из трех значений. Как сделать из произвольного количества значений???

```
sp = input().split()
num_list = [int(i) for i in sp]
result_dict = {}
result_dict = {num_list[-2]: num_list[-1]}
for i in range(len(num_list)-2):
    d = {num_list[i]: result_dict}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаём итератор, бегущий по списку задом-наперёд. Первое значение итератора - "корень" списка. Остальные значения надеваем на него в цикле:

```
def make_dict(lst):
    it = reversed(lst)
    d = next(it)
    for n in it:
        d = {n: d}
    return d

  
print(make_dict([100, 55, 77, 55, 89]))
```

> ```
> $ python make_dict.py
> {100: {55: {77: {55: 89}}}}
> ```

Или рекурсия:

```
def make_dict(lst):

    def rec(i):
        if i == len(lst) - 1:
            return lst[i]
        return {lst[i]: rec(i + 1)}

    return rec(0)
```

Или хвостовая рекурсия:

```
def make_dict(lst):

    def rec(i, d):
        if i < 0:
            return d
        return rec(i - 1, {lst[i]: d})

    return rec(len(lst) - 2, lst[-1])
```

**P.S.** Во всех вариантах список не копируется. Из-за этого возня с итератором в цикле и индексами в рекурсиях.

Answer (score 0):

**Предисловие**

Ваша задача - это небольшая модернизация типовой задачи о вложенном словаре.

В исходном виде она выглядит следующим образом - из такого списка:

```
[100, 55, 77, 55, 89]
```

Сделать вот такой словарь:

```
{100: {55: {77: {55: {89: {}}}}}}
```

И эта задача решена уже множество раз, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401886/how-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-list-in-python).

Приведу пример ее решения:

```
a = [100, 55, 77, 55, 89]

tree_dict = {}

for key in reversed(a):
    tree_dict = {key: tree_dict}

print(tree_dict)
```

Вывод:

> `{100: {55: {77: {55: {89: {}}}}}}`

**Вернемся к вашей задаче**

Отличие лишь в том, что последний элемент списка должен быть помещен не в качестве вложенного словаря, а в качестве значения.

Сделать это можно многими способами, например, перед основным алгоритмом "заготовить" нужный нам хвост словаря:

```
a = [100, 55, 77, 55, 89]

tree_dict = a[-1]

for key in reversed(a[:-1]):
    tree_dict = {key: tree_dict}

print(tree_dict)
```

Тогда уже получаем нужный нам вывод:

> `{100: {55: {77: {55: 89}}}}`